# How to get image size (not dimensions) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

I have an image element:

```
<img id="my_image" src="https://crossorigin.url/photo.jpg" onLoad=whatToPutHere() />
```

and after I load it from an external source (there is no CORS policy issue) I want to know the size of the image that will be the same same size in disk if I right click on the image and save it on my computer.

Can I avoid making a `HEAD` request to get the `Content-Length` at `"https://crossorigin.url/photo.jpg"` ?
Is there any other way to do it with pure javascript ?

Comment: The size on the disk is not necessarily the same as in `Content-Length`

Comment: @Andreas Both is fine, either content-length or size in disk, but not have to make another request.

Comment: You can avoid another request by not including the src in the HTML, and - if it's possible - loading the image to get its filesize then adding the src attribute to the img tag. If that still requests twice you may, instead, be able to convert the loaded image to data-src and dump that into the src attribute.